# PgSQL taking too much time too respond

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, amazon-rds, postgresql-9.6

last few days i am facing a weird issue on db side. A simple query taking too much time and when i am trying to connect my aws rds with pgadmin it disconnect after some seconds. this issue didn't occur before. i don't know how to solve this issues

[image: first image]

[image: 2nd image]

and here is the stats of my aws rds:

[image]

The execution plan:

```
Aggregate (cost=9315.62..9315.63 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=59379.535..59379.536 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=32669 dirtied=5
  -> Index Only Scan using users_pkey on users (cost=0.42..8758.99 rows=222652 width=0) (actual time=0.058..41652.438 rows=223966 loops=1)
     Heap Fetches: 33168
     Buffers: shared hit=32669 dirtied=5
Planning time: 0.653 ms
Execution time: 59439.600 ms
```

Here is the scenario.
I am calling an api in which my code executing 2 or 3 queries. if simple query on db taking 15 secs then a normal query will take more than 30 secs and whenever my api takes more than 30 secs the Heroku server throws H12(503 service unavailable) error and nothing will render on my front side. so i am trying to figure out why the rds db taking too much time to respond a simple db query that should respond in milli seconds. for info i am sharing one of the breakdown table of an api. we can clearly see that database taking 90% of the time.

[image]

Comment: also i am not able to connect my rds in datastudio.

Comment: after running your query @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: 59439.600 ms to count 223966 rows while doing no read IO (and just 5 writes) is abysmal.  Ask Amazon/Heroku support what the deal is.

Answer (score 0):

Counting is slow business – you have to scan all rows to count them.

That said, you could make your index-only scan faster by running `VACUUM` on the table, so that the number of "heap fetches" (to check tuple visibility) goes down.

Apart from that, the only possibility for improvement is to rewrite the table with `VACUUM (FULL)` to get rid of bloat. But don't forget to `VACUUM` again after doing that.

Comment: okay i accept counting is a slow business. but running a simple find query taking 15 secs to respond.

Comment: Simple is different from fast.

Comment: let me clear my scenario, I am calling an api in which my code executing 2 or 3 queries. if simple query on db taking 15 secs then a normal query will take more than 30 secs and whenever my api takes more than 30 secs the server throws H12(503 service unavailable)  error and nothing will render on my front side. so i am trying to figure out why the rds db taking too much time to respond  a simple db query that should respond in milli seconds.

Comment: A query that has to scan 30000 8kB-blocks to count 200000 rows is not trivial. But the times are really bad. Perhaps you got your index or table terribly bloated, and reorganizing will help.